# Get join model value along with other values in a query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models: Producer and Event.
A join model (EventRole) links the two models and stores "role" attribute:

```
create_table :event_roles do |t|
  t.integer :role
  t.references :producer, foreign_key: true
  t.references :event, foreign_key: true
end
```

I want to know how list all producers of event X, but returning the "role" of the producer in the event.

Is that even possible?

I achieved to list all producers of an event, but (as expected) it doesn't return the "role":

```
Producer.joins(:event_roles).where(event_roles: { event_id: 1 })
```

What is the most elegant way of achieving a result like this?

```
=> [
    {id: 1, name: "Producer 1", role: "manager"},
    {id: 5, name: "Producer 5", role: "admin"}
   ]
```

Comment: what are the model relationships ?

Comment: Schema of your join model?

Comment: @Beartech and Subash, i've updated the question showing the event_roles schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make the join it does not return a table like a join in the DB would, but the info is there. There are ways of getting that info like:

```
data = Producer.includes(:event_roles).where(event_roles: { event_id: 1 }).pluck(:id, :name, :role)
```

**Update:** you can of course chain my original answer into:

```
data = Producer.includes(:event_roles).where(event_roles: { event_id: 1 }).pluck(:id, :name, :role).map {|i| {id: i[0], name: i[1], role: [2]} }
```

Addendum:
    One thing I sometimes do if I want a hash data structure that includes the data from both tables I do something like this:

```
data = EventRole.includes(:producer).where(event_roles: { event_id: 1 }).group_by {|r| r.producer }
```

This returns a hash instead of an array, where each pair is an object so the form is { => event_role object, etc..}. You can then iterate over the hash and pull which ever columns from each that you need. This is more applicable where you have two tables that have multiple columns you want to be able to access...

```
data.each do |producer, event_role|  
  puts "the producer is #{producer.name} and role is #{event_role.role}"
end

=> 'the producer is Producer 1 and role is manager'
   'the producer is Producer 5 and role is admin'
```

---

Which should return something like:

```
=> [
     [1, "Producer 1", "manager"],
     [5, "Producer 5", "admin"]
   ]
```

You could then manipulate the data into a form that works for you.

```
data.map! {|i| {id: i[0], name: i[1], role: [2]} }

=> [
     {id: 1, name: "Producer 1", role: "manager"},
     {id: 5, name: "Producer 5", role: "admin"}
   ]
```

- One gotcha here to note: if you have an `includes` or `joins` with columns of the same name you need to specify which one you want:

  data = Producer.includes(:event_roles).pluck('producers.id', 'event_roles.id')

Comment: I think `joins` would do the same thing at this point with possibly a performance difference.